# What is the format for the Elements_with_Changed_Element_Type report in ClearCase from the command line?

Tags: clearcase

I cannot seem to find any DOCs on running this report.  Here us what I typed in and nothing returns.  The report returns 2000+ lines when run through the gui however it takes ten minutes to pull up all of the labels.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\reports\scripts\Elements>ccperl Elements_with_Changed_Element_Type.prl LOOKIN="J:\nfloyd_jup6\jupnms\" LABEL="
    labelabc" LABEL="labeldef"
```

Comment: Was my answer enough? Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (for this question or your other questions)

Answer (score 0):

Without the sources of "`C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\reports\scripts\Elements\Elements_with_Changed_Element_Type.prl`", it is hard to say.

Looking at "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)", it could find changed elements between labels and apply other criteria.

[This 2008 thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014080216) does mention:

the scripts are written in perl and are located in %CLEARCASEHOME%\reports\scripts...

> Just run '`ccperl %CLEARCASEHOME%\reports\scripts\...\script-name.prl`' arg-list. You'll need to take a look at the script itself to identify / check syntax for arg-list; for paths it is something like "`LOOKIN=path`" (from memory). Also, specify an absolute path (and in lowercase again from memory) as the scripts searches `$0` for '`/scripts/`' to find the common include files.

For instance:

> apparently it doesn't like a space between the various arguments... here is the command I used.

```
 C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\reports\scripts>
 ccperl "c:\program files\rational\clearcase\reports\scripts\Elements\labels\versions_with_labels.prl" LOOKIN=\"m:\cfdcnn_int\MAESTRO_SYS\cfdcnn\\\";LABEL=\"cfdcnn_cfdcnn_integratoin_9_24_07_Dev_01\"
```

Answer (score 0):

This script is pretty straightforward. It does a cleartool find -type f, and for every file that exists (since you can run this in a snapshot view containing unloaded elements), compares the current element type with the type that would be assigned by the current magic file.

The label options aren't needed, only LOOKIN:

```
C:\Users\bcowan>ccperl "\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\reports\scripts\Elements\Elements_with_Changed_Element_Type.prl" -i
description : "Elements with Changed Element Type"
id : 2021
helpfile :
parameters : LOOKIN
rightclick : Properties_of_Element(single) sep Version_Tree(single) History(single) sep Change_Element_Type
fields : "Element Path"(element_pn, sort 3, rightclick) "Element Type"(eltype) "Element's default.magic Type"(eltype, sort 2) "Element Types  Different"(yes_no, sort 1)
```

So, when I run the command:

```
C:\Users\bcowan>ccperl "\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\reports\scripts\Elements\Elements_with_Changed_Element_Type.prl" LOOKIN=\"v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\";
```

I get this:

```
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\Asm\x64\7zCrcT8U.asm;text_file;text_file;no
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\Asm\x86\7zCrcT8U.asm;text_file;text_file;no
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\C\7zBuf.h;text_file;text_file;no
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\C\7zBuf2.c;text_file;text_file;no
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\C\7zCrc.c;text_file;text_file;no
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\C\7zCrc.h;text_file;text_file;no
v:\uncview\mkvobtest\p7zip\p7zip_9.20.1\C\7zCrcOpt.c;text_file;text_file;no
...
```